# Can someone spoof a websocket connection?

Tags: security, websocket, spoofing

In the case where its beeing used a websocket protocol between a client (webpage) and a server.

- Is it possible for third parties to spoof the connection in the handshake or even after the connection has been established?

Answer (score 0):

Websockets do not directly provide authentication. If you build it over TLS (i.e. WSS), then you will use the TLS session to authenticate the parties using server and client certificates, exactly like HTTPS vs HTTP.

If you build your websocket over HTTP, then yes, it is completely possible for a third party to spoof the connection (and also to eavesdrop). If your HTTPS/WSS system does not properly validate certificates, then that also can be spoofed.